# Calculate mean euclidean distance of multiple columns dataframe r

Tags: r, dataframe, vector, euclidean-distance

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
df <- data.frame(text = c("text1", "text2", "text3"),
             a = c(1,2,3),
             b = c(2,4,6),
             c = c(3,6,9))
df
```

For each row I want to compute the mean of the distance between the values in columns a, b and c using:

```
mean(dist())
```

I want to store the outcome in a column named "score". The result should look like this:

```
df <- data.frame(text = c("text1", "text2", "text3"),
             a = c(1,2,3),
             b = c(2,4,6),
             c = c(3,6,9),
             score = c(mean(dist(c(1,2,3))),
                       mean(dist(c(2,4,6))),
                       mean(dist(c(3,6,9)))))
df
```

Searching Stackoverflow I could only find examples of converting one row to a vector. I also tried a bunch of my own approaches but each time I got stuck. This is probably due to a lack of base R knowledge. Please help me to solve this problem. I am very grateful for your help!

Comment: df$score <- apply(df[,2:4], 1, function(x) mean(dist(x)))

Comment: df$score = sapply(df[,2:4], function(x) mean(dist(x)))

Comment: @JuanAntonioRoldánDíaz answer works, thanks! I posted it as a separate answer to solve my question. Can't accept it within 2 days though..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this easy solution.

STEP 1: Create a function f doing the mean of all distance

```
f<-function(x)
{
  return(mean(dist(x)))
}
```

STEP 2:
Apply the function by each row and insert the output in `score`

```
df$score<-apply(df[,-1],1,f)
```

Your output

```
    df
   text a b c    score
1 text1 1 2 3 1.333333
2 text2 2 4 6 2.666667
3 text3 3 6 9 4.000000
```

Comment: This does not return the same values in score as were shown in the example.

Comment: Sorry, the code was right but not the copy pasting to SO. As you can see my answer has the same logic of JuanAntonioRoldanDianz one, but it's explained step by step in a more extended version. Answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will help you:

```
df <- data.frame(text = c("text1", "text2", "text3"),
             a = c(1,2,3),
             b = c(2,4,6),
             c = c(3,6,9))
score= c(mean(dist(c(1,2,3))),
      mean(dist(c(2,4,6))),
      mean(dist(c(3,6,9))))
df = cbind(df,score)
```

The result is

```
df
text a b c    score
1 text1 1 2 3 1.333333
2 text2 2 4 6 2.666667
3 text3 3 6 9 4.000000
```

A+

Answer (score 0):

@JuanAntonioRoldánDíaz posted the correct answer.

```
df$score <- apply(df[,2:4], 1, function(x) mean(dist(x)))
```